# Сворачивание и разворачивание столбцов в таблице

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Коллеги, подскажите, существует ли возможность разворачивать и сворачивать столбцы таблицы  не нарушая стандарты.
При клике на "Доход" нужно показывать/скрывать колонки относящиеся к "Структуре дохода".
Сама таблица:

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%; 
    border-spacing: 7px 11px;
}
td,th   {
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a; 
}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">Отчет по неделям</th>
    <th colspan="8">Ключевые показатели</th>
    <th colspan="6">Структура дохода</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Прибыль</th>
    <th colspan="2">Доход</th>
    <th colspan="2">Расходы</th>
    <th colspan="2">Ср.чек.</th>
    <th colspan="2">Доход 1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Доход 2</th>
    <th colspan="2">Доход 3</th>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Рекорды</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>5573</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>6423</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>1344</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>1202</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>12-10-2015</td>
    <td>18-10-2015</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="success">100 %</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="success">100 %</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="success">100 %</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="success">100 %</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="success">100%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="success">100%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="success">100 %</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Конкретней можно, что вы хотите сворачивать/разворачивать при клике?
Я вот не понял, какие столбцы вам нужно сворачивать при клике на "Доходы".

Answer (score 1):

Не пробовал ещё, но я бы попробовал назначить каждому td в соответствующей колонке уникальный id, а затем getElementById.style.display='none' (ну или ='block', если надо показать). Решение может и не идеальное, но должно работать. А другие решения не пробовали? Может как-нибудь через блочную верстку?